# Shapely Intersection return types

Tags: python, geometry, intersection, shapely

Trying to shoot a ray (LineString) through multiple shapely objects and figuring out how many intersections there are.

Having some issues though, as the intersection-method have multiple return types and I need to handle all of them in order for my program to run smoothly. The obvious ones are Point and MultiPoint but can someone tell me the rest? Have tried looking at source code and the manual, but it seems tricky to figure out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to say that the obvious return type are Point and/or MultiPoint but if your ray is exactly parallel to one or more edges of your Shapely objects than the return type will be LineString or MultiLineString.  It should never return Polygon or MultiPolygon.

Comment: Alright, guessing those are edge cases, but I might as well ensure that my program supports them. :)

Thanks!